# Heroku run rake db:seed error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am a new developer building a stripe payment processing system in Rails 4.2.4.

My application works perfect locally but when I push this to Heroku I get this error after I run `rake db:seed`.

I cannot get the application to open at production level at all now though it was working well before.

This is the error in the terminal:

```
rake aborted!
    ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:79:in `raise_record_invalid'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
    /app/db/seeds.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:183:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

This is seeds.rb:

```
AdminUser.create!(email: 'admin@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password')

placenta_wash = Product.create(title: "Placenta Wash", 
 subtitle: "Nippon Beauty", author: "Chris Dorman", 
 length: "30 minutes", author_image_name: "teacher-image.jpg", 
 price: "4.99", sku: "GROHACK1", download_url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/one-month-stripe-payments-dorman/CV.pdf", 
 details: "You'll get one video", description: %{<p>A growth hacker is a rare combination: someone with the right marketing and technical skills who can come up with clever marketing hacks and also track their results.</p>

 <p>In this talk, Mattan Griffel introduces you to the concept of Growth Hacking and shares his favorite tips for getting started as a growth hacker.</p>
 <p><strong>What You'll Learn</strong></p>
 <ul class="no-indent">
 <li>What is a growth hacker?</li>
 <li>The 5 stages of the user lifecycle</li>
 <li>How to apply the Lean Marketing Framework</li>
 <li>Resources and tools you'll need to know</li>
 </ul>}, 
 author_description: %{ <p>Hey, I'm Mattan Griffel, co-founder of the Y Combinator backed <a href="http://www.onemonth.com" target="_blank">One Month</a> where I teach the best selling One Month Rails and One Month Growth Hacking.</p>
 <p>Why take my class? In the past I've advised companies like Pepsico, Bloomberg, GM, NYSE, and JPMorgan on growth hacking best practices. I've also spoken at New York University, Cooper Union and First Round Capital. My goal is to help you and other entrepreneurs rapidly grow your business. 
 </p>
 <p>Follow me on Twitter <a href="https://twitter.com/mattangriffel" target="_blank">@mattangriffel</a></p>})

growth_hacking_monthly = Product.create(title: "Growth Hacking Monthly", 
 subtitle: "Ongoing Course", author: "Chris Dorman", 
 length: "6 months", author_image_name: "teacher-image.jpg", 
 price: "4.99", sku: "GROHACK2", download_url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/one-month-stripe-payments/Peter+Bell+Resume.pdf", 
 details: "We'll charge you monthly for unlimited access to our mentoring team", description: %{<p>A growth hacker is a rare combination: someone with the right marketing and technical skills who can come up with clever marketing hacks and also track their results.</p>

 <p>In this series, Mattan Griffel introduces you to the concept of Growth Hacking and shares his favorite tips for getting started as a growth hacker.</p>
 <p><strong>What You'll Learn</strong></p>
 <ul class="no-indent">
 <li>What is a growth hacker?</li>
 <li>The 5 stages of the user lifecycle</li>
 <li>How to apply the Lean Marketing Framework</li>
 <li>Resources and tools you'll need to know</li>
 </ul>}, 
 author_description: %{ <p>Hey, I'm Mattan Griffel, co-founder of the Y Combinator backed <a href="http://www.onemonth.com" target="_blank">One Month</a> where I teach the best selling One Month Rails and One Month Growth Hacking.</p>
 <p>Why take my class? In the past I've advised companies like Pepsico, Bloomberg, GM, NYSE, and JPMorgan on growth hacking best practices. I've also spoken at New York University, Cooper Union and First Round Capital. My goal is to help you and other entrepreneurs rapidly grow your business. 
 </p>
 <p>Follow me on Twitter <a href="https://twitter.com/mattangriffel" target="_blank">@mattangriffel</a></p>})
```

Comment: Are you running `heroku run rake db:seed` for the first time or have you ran it before also?

Comment: Can you post your seeds.rb file?

Comment: would you like my seed file posted as a jpg or in the block quote. thanks

Comment: I have ran it before, git push heroku master, then heroku run rake db:migrate and then heroku run rake db:seed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this because you have a uniqueness validation on the email field of your AdminUser model. The seed is failing because the record you are creating on line one of your seends.rb is invalid due to the email [not being unique](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness). This problem is not Heroku specific--it should fail the same way if you run `rake db:seed` locally, twice in a row.

You might try adding something like `AdminUser.destroy_all` to your seeds.rb file (or whatever the name of the model is if it's not User). I would be **very** careful with that though as you would not want to delete production data.

Better still, just add `unless AdminUser.find_by(email: 'admin@example.com')` to the end of the first line of your seeds file.

If you are simply looking to add some data to your app, you might want to look at creating a populate task. There is a [RailsCast on this subject](http://railscasts.com/episodes/126-populating-a-database).

Comment: im not clear on your instructions. its working perfect locally, I can't get the page loaded at all in heroku

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. Your seed is failing because there already an AdminUser with 'admin@example.com' in your system. You could do a number of things to solve this: the easiest might be to wrap the creation of the AdminUser on line 1 of your seed file in an `unless AdminUser.find_by(email: 'admin@example.com')`

Comment: the seed is not failing at local level though

Comment: please code this into my seed file above and show me

Comment: Interesting that it is not failing at the local level. Two questions: are you using Devise and how many AdminUsers exist in your local database with the email 'admin@example.com'?

Comment: The first line of your seed file should read (in my opinion): `AdminUser.create!(email: 'admin@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password') unless AdminUser.find_by(email: 'admin@example.com')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105183/discussion-between-m00b-and-chris-dormani).